# Closed affine subspace of $\mathcal{L}^{2}$

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, hilbert-spaces

Consider a Hilbert space $\mathcal{L}^{2}=\lbrace X: X-\text{real-valued random variable}, \mathbb{E}(X^{2})<\infty \rbrace$ with the inner product $\langle X,Y\rangle=\mathbb{E}(XY)$.  Let $X_{1},...,X_{n},\mu(\Theta)\in\mathcal{L}^{2}$ and $M(X)$ be defined as

$M(X):=\lbrace \widehat{\mu(\Theta)}: \widehat{\mu(\Theta)}=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}a_{j}X_{j}, \hspace{2mm}a_{1},...,a_{n}\in\mathbb{R},\hspace{2mm} \mathbb{E}\left[\widehat{\mu(\Theta)}  \right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\mu(\Theta)  \right]\rbrace$

So, elements of $M(X)$ are homogenous estimators of some unknown random variable $\mu(\Theta)$. My questions: why is $M(X)$ an $\textbf{affine subspace}$ of $\mathcal{L}^{2}$?